# How to get Task startdate and due date using EWS java API

Tags: exchangewebservices, ewsjavaapi, microsoft-exchange

I am trying to fetch task details from Microsoft Exchange Server using following code

```
    public List readTask() throws Exception{
    //Create the extended property definition.
     try {
    Task t=new Task(service);
    ExtendedPropertyDefinition taskCompleteProp = new 
    ExtendedPropertyDefinition(DefaultExtendedPropertySet.Task, 0x0000811C, 
    MapiPropertyType.Boolean);
    //Create the search filter.
    SearchFilter.IsEqualTo filter = new 
    SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(taskCompleteProp, false);                    
    //Get the tasks.

    FindItemsResults<Item> tasks = 
    service.findItems(WellKnownFolderName.Tasks, filter, new ItemView(50));

    service.loadPropertiesForItems(tasks.getItems(), new PropertySet());

    for(Item task:tasks){
        task.load();
        System.out.println(task.getSubject());
        System.out.println(task.getBody());


    }
    return null;
    }
```

How should i get the task start and duedate of particular task in for loop

Answer (score 0):

it was really very simple.

```
      for(Item task:tasks){
        task.load();
        Task tde=(Task) task;
        System.out.println(tde.getSubject());
        System.out.println(tde.getBody());
        System.out.println(tde.getStartDate());
        System.out.println(tde.getDueDate());
       }
```